# Appending an integer slice to a slice of integer slices modifies the slice that gets appended

Tags: go, append, slice

I'm trying to append a slice of integers to a slice that is made up of integer slices. When I print the slice, it shows up as expected. However, when I append the slice to a slice of slices, the content changes.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var myGraph [8][8]bool //the graph

var visited [8]bool //an array that marks if visited

var path []int //a slice to store a possible path

var paths [][]int

func dfs(src int, dest int) {
    //add current node to path
    path = append(path, src)

    //mark current node as visited
    visited[src] = true

    //if the current node is the destination
    //print the path and return
    if src == dest {
        fmt.Println(path)
        paths = append(paths, path) //I'm trying to push the path slice into the paths slice
        return
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 7; i++ { //loop through all nodes

        //if ith node is a neighbour of the current node and it is not visited
        if myGraph[src][i] && visited[i] == false {

            // call dfs on the current node
            dfs(i, dest)

            //mark the current node as unvisited
            //so that we can other paths to the final destination
            visited[i] = false

            //re-slice the slice - get rid of the current node
            path = path[:len(path)-1]
        }

    }

}

func main() {
    path = make([]int, 0, 8)
    paths = make([][]int, 0, 10)

    //creating the graph
    myGraph[1] = [...]bool{false, false, true, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[2] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false}
    myGraph[3] = [...]bool{false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false}
    myGraph[4] = [...]bool{false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[5] = [...]bool{false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[6] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true}
    myGraph[7] = [...]bool{false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false}

    //call dfs by feeding in the source and the destination
    dfs(1, 7)
    fmt.Println(paths)
}

Output:
[1 2 5 6 7]
[1 3 2 5 6 7]
[1 3 4 6 7]
[1 3 6 7]
[1 6 7]
[[1 6 7 3 2 5] [1 6 7 3 2] [1 6 7 3 2] [1 6 7 3 2 5] [1 6 7 3 2] [1 6 7 3] [1 6 7]]
```

As you can see, the slice of slices is printed at the end by the main function. However, its contents are different to the individual slices that are printed by dfs().

Answer (score 1):

Let's change this code a bit:

```
var myGraph [8][8]bool //the graph

var visited [8]bool //an array that marks if visited

var path []int //a slice to store a possible path

var paths [][]int

func dfs(src int, dest int) {
    //add current node to path
    path = append(path, src)

    //mark current node as visited
    visited[src] = true

    //if the current node is the destination
    //print the path and return
    if src == dest {
        // (A)
        buffer := make([]int, len(path))
        copy(buffer, path)

        fmt.Println(buffer)
        paths = append(paths, buffer) //I'm trying to push the path slice into the paths slice

        // fmt.Println(path)
        // paths = append(paths, path) //I'm trying to push the path slice into the paths slice
        return
    }

    for i := 1; i <= 7; i++ { //loop through all nodes

        //if ith node is a neighbour of the current node and it is not visited
        if myGraph[src][i] && visited[i] == false {

            // call dfs on the current node
            dfs(i, dest)

            //mark the current node as unvisited
            //so that we can other paths to the final destination
            visited[i] = false

            //re-slice the slice - get rid of the current node
            path = path[:len(path)-1]
        }

    }

}

func main1() {
    // path = make([]int, 0, 8)
    // paths = make([][]int, 0, 10)

    //creating the graph
    myGraph[1] = [...]bool{false, false, true, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[2] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false}
    myGraph[3] = [...]bool{false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false}
    myGraph[4] = [...]bool{false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[5] = [...]bool{false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false}
    myGraph[6] = [...]bool{false, true, false, true, true, false, false, true}
    myGraph[7] = [...]bool{false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false}

    //call dfs by feeding in the source and the destination
    dfs(1, 7)
    fmt.Println(paths)
}
```

And now it works as expected! Why? Because slices are reference types, not value types; means when you change `path` later, you will see that new value unless you take a snapshot of it like what is done at `// (A)`.

Comment: Thank you. And I'm guessing fmt.Println was giving me expected results because that is also a kind of "snapshot".

Comment: I'm new to Go and I was wondering if it was possible to enhance this project. I'm trying to write a function that would take in a Graph, src and dest and spit out a slice of paths. However, right now I'm making use of global variables. I was trying to do it using nested functions but seems like Go does not allow that. Any advice?

Comment: 1 - Underling; fmt.Println sends it's arguments to a channel. At the time of actually evaluating the arguments, they are changed - in this case; because they are reference type.

Comment: 2 - Honestly I have not a clear understanding of what are you trying to achieve here. But there are good libraries for handling graphs in Go. Personally I would start with a node struct and the like; using slices and arrays may make it more efficient to some extend. But it's hard to make it concurrent past that limit.